# Selenium Expected Conditions, where does the instance of Webdriver come from?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, expected-condition

I am struggling to figure out how the WebDriver instance is passed to Selenium's expected conditions.

So I have a simple WebDriverWait for the visibility of a web element:

```
new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Configuration.WEB_DRIVER_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

The webDriver instance here is a chromedriver which has been instantiated above.

My question is: in the method visibilityOf():

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOf(final WebElement element) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
      @Override
      public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return elementIfVisible(element);
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "visibility of " + element;
      }
    };
  }
```

Just above, **how and which instance of WebDriver gets passed to the apply()**?
I understand that the ExpectedCondition implements the Function Interface

```
public interface ExpectedCondition<T> extends Function<WebDriver, T> {}
```

which takes as first argument WebDriver.

How the instance of the WebDriver gets passed to ExpectedCondition of the visibilytOf()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating the `WebDriverWait` you are passing the webdriver instance. The same instance will be passed to the `apply` method of the functional interface of `ExpectedCondition` by the `until` method.

`WebDriverWait` extends `FluentWait<WebDriver>` which actually implements the `until` method. When you construct the `WebDriverWait` the driver is passed as a parameter to `FluentWait` which keeps it in a attribute.

Now when you call `until` on `WebDriverWait` the `until` method calls the `apply` method passing the `driver` you actually passed to the constructor. The `ExpectedCondition` object that you are constructing in-effect receives two inputs. The `WebElement` you are passing to it as well as the `driver` that you pass to `WebDriverWait`.

The source code is not too complicated - you can have a look at it for finer details :)

Comment: In the javadocs of WebDriverWait it says:  @param driver The WebDriver instance to pass to the expected conditions. Could you please explain how this is passed via the until method? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the point of the call to the parent method (FluentWait) from the constructor of WebDriverWait. Thanks.